# Prevent WPF Ribbon Tab Collapse

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I noticed today that when using the WPF Ribbon control, if the user doubleclicks on the tab header, it will collapse the ribbon. Does anyone know of a way to disable this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the Ribbon Control installed on my machine but I would check out this website:

[Ribbon Control Properties](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=554)